# Safety Mode on YouTube

Tags: youtube

For some reason, when I try to turn off my safety mode on YouTube, it says “contact your network administrator.” But I don't have a network administrator, it's my personal computer so I have no clue what to do. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you signed in to a regular consumer Google account or a Google apps account?

Comment: Try to signup with normal account and have a look at this https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/174084?hl=en which may guide you with some idea.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Google Apps account? Looks like a Google bug that links the settings of your personal account to the ones of your Google Apps account.
Try to logout and login again, because maybe is fixed in Chrome v41+

Google Apps administrators, can login in the admin dashboard, open Device Management, select Chrome and set the Safe Search to 'Do not enforce Safe Search for Google'